# Delay on Loading Contents while Using Transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions

I felt some delay on Loading Contents while Using Transactions to Edit the contents,
(Testing this situation is a bit hard for me as I don't know how could be better to test it)

I have some doubts about `Transactions` usages:

There are some minor issues and things I should understand about Transactions
and these parts are related to this question :

**When should we use Transactions in a Own-Made CMS ?**

My-case-specific notes :

1. Should I use transactions on any CMS , While we have sprocs on Insert,Update,Retrieve, .... ?
2. Is the necessity of using transactions just when we are working on more tables than one ?

The Transaction strategy I used :

**Adding Product Method ( Which uses add Product sproc ) :**

```
            TransactionOptions txOptions = new TransactionOptions();
            using (TransactionScope txScope = new TransactionScope
              (TransactionScopeOption.Required, txOptions))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    LastInserted = (int)pInsertedID.Value;
                    txScope.Complete();                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logErrors.Warn(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Who made the CMS is not too relevant. You appear to update only 1 table so the tx is not doing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions may help to ensure consistency of the database. For example, if a stored procedure used to add a product inserts data in more than one table, and something fails along the way, a transaction might be helpful to rollback the whole operation, thus the database is free of half-baked products (e.g. lacking some critical info in related tables).

Transaction scopes (`TransactionScope`) are used to provide an ambient implicit transaction for whatever code runs inside a code block. These scopes may help to severely simplify the code, however, they also may add complexities in multithreaded environments (unfortunately, I don't know quite a lot about such cases).

Therefore, the code you provided would probably make sense to ensure database's consistency, especially if the command uses more than one table. It may add some performance overhead; however, you would be better off relying on gathered profiling data rather than any sort of feelings before conducting any optimizations (i.e. try to gather some quantitative data as to how slower things are under transactions). Modern database engines usually handle transactions quite efficiently; in my own experience, there were no transactions for removal due to their performance overhead.